# How to see data crawled by nutch using solr?

Tags: apache, solr, lucene, nutch

I am new to Nutch and Solr. So, I apologize in advance if I am asking basic  question.

Details of environment:

1. Virtual Box with Guest OS: Ubuntu 12.04.4, Host OS: Windows 8
2. Nutch Release: Apache nutch 1.7
3. Solr Release: Apache Solr 3.6.2
4. Referring to wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchTutorial

I initiated crawling with command-

```
bin/nutch crawl urls -solr http://<code>mylocalhost<code>:8983/solr/ -depth 3 -topN 5
```

This command succeeded with no errors.

After that, I opened the solr admin page in browser and tried to search with a default query string: `\*:*`.  However, this resulted in a page with the below content:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<response>
    <lst name="responseHeader">
        <int name="status">0</int>
        <int name="QTime">0</int>
        <lst name="params">
            <str name="start">0</str>
            <str name="q">*:*</str>
            <str name="rows">10</str>
            <str name="indent">on</str>
            <str name="version">2.2</str>
        </lst>
    </lst>
    <result name="response" numFound="0" start="0"/>
</response>
```

When I tried to search for 'nutch' in solr, it resulted in an error: "HTTP Error 400".

Could you please help me see data crawled by nutch so that I can validate it.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to validate your data sounds like what you are trying to do: query the data and make sure it returns the expected results. 
Some help there:

When you say you tried a basic query string, do you mean from the solr admin, or through the rest API?   If you are using the solr admin, you don't need to escape that first *. So q would be *:* directly.  In the Rest API, the * needs to be properly encoded. Something like this:

```
http://your_host_name:8888/solr/your_core_name/select?q=*%3A*&wt=json&indent=true
```

Another thing you can do is validate some of nutch's intermediary data is to dump the crawl or link dbs using the bin/nutch commands readdb, readlinkdb, mergedb.

Comment: Thank you so much for you reply!

After some more analysis I found that the default search field (i.e., <defaultSearchField>content</defaultSearchField>) present in schema.xml (schema.xml copied from conf directory of nutch) was not matching with the one from solrconfig.xml (i.e., <str name="df">text</str> ). Notice that 'content' against 'text'.
The problem got resolved after changing 'text' to 'content' in <str name="df">text</str>.

After that I could configure 'nutch' (2.2.1) with HBase (0.90.4). I could crawl the data but now I don't know how to verify the same.

Comment: OK, so then the problem is writing your verification test? You need to  compare the output from your query to the output you expected to get for the crawled site.   So if you were crawling a file system where the doc id is the filesystem path, you might compare the results of an ls -R to a query where q is *.*, and fl:id.  Web sites could do something similar if you have a site index. What kind of data are you trying to browse?

Comment: My main aim is to crawl a websites for product details and store this crawled information in HBase. I could crawl the data and it got stored in HBase. However, when I scan the particular table from HBase, I don't see the data from the crawled site. For this particular issue, I have created separate thread at- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23564206/unable-to-verify-crawled-data-stored-in-hbase
Could you please take a look at this thread and let me know your thought. I would be extremely thankful to you for any help provided in this regards.

Comment: Sorry, have only used it with the 1.x-series Hadoop wrt your new question.  If you are sure your data isn't getting to Solr, useing the readdb commands to get more information as to whether your crawls are succeeding or now.